# Get PID of nohup process through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, pid

I would like to get the PID of a process I start through ssh.

I have a bash script and here is what I wrote:

```
SSH_COMMAND='ssh'
cmd=`eval $my_cmd`
PROG_CMD="$program $cmd"
$SSH_COMMAND root@server "(nohup $PROG_CMD) & echo "'$!'" > prog.pid"
```

Note that variables "program" and "my_cmd" are defined in a JSON file (and contain, respectively, my program and the command to start my program).

My program is started on the server exactly the way it is supposed to start but I do not have the correct PID (i.e : the PID of program) in the `prog.pid` file.

EDIT : I did an echo of the SSH_COMMAND and I got :

```
 ssh root@server (my_program args > output.log 2>&1 & ) & echo $! > prog.pid
```

args : arguments of my_program

output.log : log file of my program

Comment: where the prog.pid is expected in root's home directory of server ?

Comment: Nope, the prog.pid is located on the "local machine", where I do the ssh command. But the issues is not here. I have the prog.pid file with a PID wrote inside... it is just not the correct one !

Comment: in the first command prog.id was inside ssh command between double quotes so expected on remote

Comment: The quotes are good imho.

Comment: I didn't say quotes were wrong, but the command was not doing expected because as is the first command would create a file on remote server in current working directory by default root's home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `(command &) &`. Just use `(command) &` (or just `command &`). With `(command &) &`, Bash needs to *fork* another sub-shell to run the command so `$!` would be the *PID* of the sub-shell other than the command.

See following example:

```
$ (nohup sleep 1234 > /dev/null 2>&1 &) &
[1] 44420      <=== this is the PID of the sub-shell which died immediately
$
[1]+  Done  ( nohup sleep 1234 > /dev/null 2>&1 & )
$ ps p 44420   <=== as you can see this PID does not exist any more
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
$ ps -C sleep u
USER        PID  TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      44421  pts/13   S    17:48   0:00 sleep 1234
$ kill 44421
```

This would work fine:

```
$ (nohup sleep 1234 > /dev/null 2>&1) &
[1] 44424         <=== this is the PID of the sleep command
$ ps p 44424 u
USER        PID  TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      44424  pts/13   S    17:49   0:00 sleep 1234
```

Comment: You were right, I deleted the & and the PID was the correct one. Moreover, your answer explains perfectly what happens, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To write the file prog.pid (with remote pid) on the local machine just put out the redirection from inside quotes

```
$SSH_COMMAND root@server "(nohup $PROG_CMD) & echo "'$!' > prog.pid
```

If the pid wanted is ssh local process `echo $!` must be taken out ssh command

```
$SSH_COMMAND root@server "(nohup $PROG_CMD)" & echo $! > prog.pid
```

Comment: Nope, I tried and it did not change anything. The issue is not about writing PID in a file but writing the good PID !

Comment: Have you read correctly the answer as in the question it is not clear which PID is interesting, the first command gives the PID of nohup command executed on remote server, whereas the second the PID of local ssh command

Comment: I am interested in getting the PID of nohup command, I tried your answer putting out the redirection from inside quotes and the PID in the prog.pid was 11043 whereas the real PID of my program was 11044.

Comment: it may be due to parentheses that were initially they start a sub-shell so 11043 is the PID of remote shell process and 11044 of the sub-shell, just remove the parentheses

Comment: I’m not sure but the answer from @whjm solved the issue.

Comment: i think understood $PROG_CMD expanded with ampersand at the end, and you fixed it by removing this ampersand